# Flutter image.network() crash the apps

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter apps crash during development. It directly crash if I use this image.

[My image that has error](https://testpmcstorage.blob.core.windows.net/background-image/image7.jpeg)

```
 Image.network(
               'https://testpmcstorage.blob.core.windows.net/background-image/image7.jpeg',)
```

Comment: What is the error message that appears in the console?

Comment: Facing the same issue [console log] - [VERBOSE-2:image_descriptor.cc(181)] Failed to get pixels for image.
Lost connection to device.

Comment: In flutter 2, the crash is fixed, But still image is not rendering.